# How can I put values from an array into an HTML Table?

Tags: php, html, curl, multidimensional-array, html-table

I am trying to use the Google Contacts API to show all my contacts. I followed an tutorial, but sadly this tutorial doesnt show how to show the data on my website. I am also using Google App Engine and PHPStorm if it matters...

Main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Naam </th>
        <th>Email </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    include('response-callback.php');
    foreach ($google_contacts as $contacts){
        echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td>'. $contacts['title']."</td>";
        echo'<td>'. $contacts['gd$email'].'</td>';
        echo'</tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>

</body>

</html>
```

Response-callback.php

```
require_once '../../../mike/Documents/google-api-php-client-1-master/src/Google/autoload.php';

$google_client_id = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$google_client_secret = 'xxxxxxx';
$google_redirect_uri = 'https://xxxxxxx-xxxx.appspot.com/main.php';

//setup new google client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName('ImportContacts');
$client -> setClientid($google_client_id);
$client -> setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$client -> setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri);
$client -> setAccessType('online');

$client -> setScopes('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds');

$googleImportUrl = $client -> createAuthUrl();

function curl($url, $post = "") {
    $curl = curl_init();
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.
    if ($post != "") {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 5);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
    $contents = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $contents;
}

//google response with contact. We set a session and redirect back
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $auth_code = $_GET["code"];
    $_SESSION['google_code'] = $auth_code;
    header('Location: ' . $google_redirect_uri);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['google_code'])) {
    $auth_code = $_SESSION['google_code'];
    $max_results = 200;
    $fields=array(
        'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
        'client_id'=>  urlencode($google_client_id),
        'client_secret'=>  urlencode($google_client_secret),
        'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($google_redirect_uri),
        'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
    );
    $post = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    {
        $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $post = rtrim($post,'&');
    $result = curl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',$post);
    $response =  json_decode($result);
    $accesstoken = $response->access_token;
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
    $xmlresponse =  curl($url);
    $contacts = json_decode($xmlresponse,true);
    $return = array();
    if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
        foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
            //retrieve Name and email address
            $return[] = array (
                'name'=> $contact['title']['$t'],
                'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
            );
        }
    }
    $google_contacts = $return;
    unset($_SESSION['google_code']);
}
```

Comment: Just saying... i have never worked with php, google app engine or even api's before.

Comment: yeah.. i know :/ at school we only did microsoft stuff

Comment: You must to change of school. Microsoft stuff means click and click and click to develop apps. A crap. But in this case, how to help you if you don't know nothing about PHP or how APIs works?

Comment: If you want some useful help tell us what is wrong with the script. I can see one obvious error and have added an answer to resolve that. I am not going to look in-depth to find problems unless you give us more information about what is wrong.

Comment: @marcos thats why everybody hates my ***** school... they get paid by microsoft to teach use those things...

Tom i understand... but that one error was really the only one needed to get fixed. Still thanks though

Comment: I believe you. I know some schools here in Spain that makes the same. The students basically don't find work when finish the course, they only work in a .NET project or something similar, but when they need to open a terminal or codifying something, they are scared and run like Forrest Gump. I recommend you to learn by yourself, most of us made that in some moment of our lives. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong array keys when you iterate through the $google_contacts array.

Change this

```
foreach ($google_contacts as $contacts){
    echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td>'. $contacts['title']."</td>";
    echo'<td>'. $contacts['gd$email'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
}
```

To this

```
foreach ($google_contacts as $contacts){
    echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td>'. $contacts['name']."</td>";
    echo'<td>'. $contacts['email'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Here you are a XML example of the response: http://laravel.io/bin/oke2w where do you see the `name` and  `email` keys come?

Comment: Ok, I see now, Sorry

Comment: He gets the exact code from here: https://www.design19.org/blog/import-google-contacts-with-php-or-javascript-using-google-contacts-api-and-oauth-2-0/

Comment: @MikeLammers if this solves the problem, upvote and accept as correct answer

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I am seeing those keys towards the bottom of `Response-callback.php`

Comment: yes tom, I see it when I said sorry. But seems that is not the only problem here.

Comment: If that was not the only problem, please edit your question and provide all errors that you can see.